FileRobot image quality on save when rotating or performing an action
So i have defined the following component in my react ts application.
<FilerobotImageEditor
              source={
                imageHistory[panel].length && imageHistory[panel][0].imgSrc
                  ? (imageHistory[panel][0].imgSrc as string)
                  : imgUrl
              }
              savingPixelRatio={100}
              avoidChangesNotSavedAlertOnLeave={true}
              previewPixelRatio={100}
              updateStateFnRef={imageRef}
              // onModify={onModify}
              defaultToolId={TOOLS.BRIGHTNESS}
              removeSaveButton
              observePluginContainerSize
              Text={{ text: 'Please add annotation' }}
              Ellipse={{
                strokeWidth: 4,
                shadowOffsetX: 0,
                shadowOffsetY: 0,
                shadowBlur: 0,
                shadowColor: '#000000',
                shadowOpacity: 1,
                opacity: 0.85,
              }}
              useBackendTranslations={false}
              tabsIds={[TABS.ADJUST, TABS.FINETUNE, TABS.ANNOTATE]}
              getCurrentImgDataFnRef={imageRefToBeSaved!}
              resetOnImageSourceChange={true}
              defaultSavedImageQuality={1}
            />

I have defined upon change the following
 const saveImageToFile = (imageRef: TypeAny) => {
    const currentImageData = imageRef.current();

    if (currentImageData) {
      // Assume you extract the original image's dimensions from the attributes
      const originalWidth = currentImageData.imageData.imageCanvas.attributes.width.value;
      const originalHeight = currentImageData.imageData.imageCanvas.attributes.height.value;

      // Set the original size back after rotation or transformation
      const imageFileInfo = {
        name: 'image', // Custom name if needed
        extension: 'png', // Keep it as PNG for lossless quality
        size: {
          width: originalWidth, // Restore to original width
          height: originalHeight, // Restore to original height
        },
      };

      // Retrieve the image data from Filerobot
      const updatedImageData = imageRef.current(imageFileInfo, false, false);

      if (updatedImageData) {
        // Convert the base64 to a Blob for saving
        const mimeType = updatedImageData.imageData.mimeType || 'image/png';
        const base64Data = updatedImageData.imageData.imageBase64;

        return base64ToBlob(base64Data, mimeType);
      }
    }
  };

  const base64ToBlob = (base64: any, mime: any) => {
    const byteString = atob(base64.split(',')[1]); // Decode base64
    const ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    const ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ab], { type: mime });
  };



in order to save the new image.
The thing is that the quality keeps on deteriorating per operation.
Would love to hear any suggestions.
I have tried multiple things from accessing canvas element to different conversions but to no avail.
